# falcor: using indexes in paths to set an items value

Tags: falcor

What is the suggested approach for updating an objects value in an array, bearing in mind the array may have been reordered?

I'm wondering how dangerous using index based paths is, when an array could have possibly changed via a deletion, or reorder. 
Would it be better to use objects instead, I wonder.

Comment: Can you append some code or examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mutable list, it is inherently unsafe to update an object by its position in a list. The right thing to do is to use deref. Assuming you have a list of references (the most common case) you can dereference a Model at its position in the list. This will ensure it points to the object's identity path rather than the index in the list. Then you can update the object directly without worrying about whether it has moved around in the list.